# Can React Router make multiple Routes visible at once and encoded in URL at once (desirable solution not failure)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

React router has the usual code:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/order/:id' component={() => <OrderPage/>}/>
   <Route exact path='/schedule/:orderid/:piececode' component={SchedulePage}/>
   <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm}/>
   <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
   <Route path='/sales/invoicelist' component={InvoiceListPage}/>
   <Route path='/sales/invoice' component={InvoicePage}/>
</Switch>
```

which facilitates, that one component (as specified in the Route that corresponds to the current URL) is instantiated and made visible in the React app.

But one can image the use cases when several root-level components should be made visible/available at once, like:

1. Multi-tab applications: the user wants to work with multiple invoices at once and she is opening multiple invoices in the app-level-tabs (not browser level) - each invoice in each page. So, she can keep editing one invoice while looking data from the other invoice. At the end of the session the use copies URL and sends via email to the collegue - she expects that collegue will be able to open the eaxact those pages;
2. stock trading application with multiple visible componens - share prices, data entry components for multiple stocks etc.

Does React Route has the capability to shoe multiple compoents and once and accept the URL which is concatenation (or some other combination) or multiple routes?

I have searched SO for this and there are similar questions, but all of them perceive such situation as the failure, e.g. they start to use Switch to show only one component.

Does React Router has capability for multiple visible routes and how such capability can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, let's take for example

```js
<Route exact path='/order/:id' component={() => <OrderPage/>}/>
```

Your component OrderPage can have nested `Route` & `Switch`

```js
const OrderPage = () => {
    return (<>
        <div>
        ....
        </div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/order/:id/tab1' component={Tab1}/>
            <Route exact path='/order/:id/tab2' component={Tab2}/>
        </switch>
    </>)
}
```

And to have this to work, and properly propagate url params, you need to remove the `exact` prop on your first route, and have all available url in your main route `path`

```js
<Route path={['/order/:id/tab1', '/order/:id/tab2', '/order/:id']} component={OrderPage}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is NO. Through react-router you can not have multiple concatenated URL's at the same time to render multiple pages.

But this can be achieved by designing the routes in a proper way such as for the example

> Multi-tab applications: the user wants to work with multiple invoices
> at once and she is opening multiple invoices in the app-level-tabs
> (not browser level) - each invoice in each page. So, she can keep
> editing one invoice while looking data from the other invoice. At the
> end of the session the use copies URL and sends via email to the
> collegue - she expects that collegue will be able to open the eaxact
> those pages;

```
<Route exact path={['/order/:id/', '/order/:id/:refenceId']} component={() => <InvoicePage/>}/>
```

In this case, you can check if URL has `referenceId` then render the referenced invoice.

OR

By using query-paramters.
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters
Add the referencedId in the query param and that can be shared

Through query-param it can even support your second usecase.

Answer (score 1):

`Switch` component renders only one child route that matches current location. So if you want to render multiple `Route` components that match current location at once, you have to omit `Switch`.

For example, if you want both SalesPage and InvoicePage being rendered for `/sales/invoice` path you could do the following:

```
<>
   <Route path='/sales' component={SalesPage}/>
   <Route path='/sales/invoice' component={InvoicePage}/>
</>
```